# How do I allow custom date field over 10 years ago?

Tags: custom-fields, profile, dates, date-preferences

Civi 4.7.3 and Wordpress 4.4.2

Since upgrade from 4.7 to 4.7.3 I cannot seem to add a custom date field and allow the user to select a date older than 10 years ago. Recreated on Demo site:
 [Click here to view demo field.](http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fcustom%2Fgroup%2Ffield&reset=1&new=1&gid=6&action=browse)

I set the options to allow 90 years before previous date,  but still I only get last 10 years in the list from the calendar.

Shall I raise this on Jira?

Answer (score 2):

> Also posting my answer to [How do I override the default date range of JQuery date widget?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10435/how-do-i-override-the-default-date-range-of-jquery-date-widget) here - for those following this Question:

I think the answer may be that this is working in 4.7.7 - set your date range in the Custom Field - Edit screen [I want to go back 30 years]:

Custom Date SE field:
[image]

And this is indeed giving me a dropdown going back 30 years (I can select 1986):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked this on the demo site.  It appears that you can type in any date up to the limit (in this case dates after and including 1 Jan 1926).  However, the date picker widget only shows the last ten years.

I'm not sure you would want the date picker widget to show all 90 years as that would make the drop down list very long. So I think this may be working as designed.

Comment: Agree, CiviCRM seems to be behaving correctly, but that is slightly odd behavior on the part of the datepicker... not sure if it's a "bug" in jQuery ui or just a questionable design choice.

Comment: I don't think this is good design, if it is intended. The core Date of Birth field does not behave like this. I am asking a user to enter their qualification date. The age of users could be between 16 and 65. Therefore, as with the CiviCRM core "Date of Birth" field, I need the drop down list to go back more than ten years. Asking a user to type in manually is fine. How can I disable the JQuery date widget (There are many bugs with this and it would be good to just disable it as a workaround).

Comment: I agree that it isn't a great user experience.  If you want to disable the widget I suggest you ask this as a separate question.

Comment: Just asked separate question. http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10389/how-can-i-disable-the-jquery-date-widget-and-all-just-text-input

Comment: @Coleman is there a way to easily override the default date period for the widget? It seems to be yearRange = "-10:+10" but I can't find this in calender.tpl template.

Answer (score 0):

We noticed the same issue, but it was only happening if eg we set a years for the past and not set one for the future. If we also added one for the future it worked.

Our thinking is that if only is one set then the options are potentially infinite and hence the default +/- 10 kicks in