# How can I disable the JQuery date widget and all just text input?

Tags: dates, date-preferences

CiviCRM 4.7.3 Worpdress 4.4.2

Due to issues with the JQuery date widget (e.g. Month and year, or year only formats are not saved and date list only goes back 10 years), I would like to simply disable it to avoid any confusion.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following CSS disables the date picker widget and allows users to simply type the date into the field:-

```
#ui-datepicker-div, .ui-datepicker .ui-widget  { display: none !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also set your date preferences in Administer >>Localization >>Date formats (possible you'd also need to look at Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Date Preferences depending on your needs.)

If it's a custom date field, you could easily set the date input preference to Month and year and increase the date range as needed.