# How do I override the default date range of JQuery date widget?

Tags: dates, date-preferences

CiviCRM 4.7.3 Currently hard coded to show 10 years in the past, and 9 years in the future.

I would like to override this and set the year range from 1965 to the current date, as described in the docs:-

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adjusting the settings at **Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Date Preferences**.  to achieve what you want?

Comment: Hi @JoAnne yes tried updating the default 'custom' offsets, and the custom field date ranges, but neither settings are picked up by the Jquery UI date picker widget. This is not being considered a bug as such, rather a poor design choice: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10319/how-do-i-allow-custom-date-field-over-10-years-ago so looking for ways to work around the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer may be that this is working in 4.7.7 - set your date range in the Custom Field - Edit screen [I want to go back 30 years]:

Custom Date SE field:
[image]

And this is indeed giving me a dropdown going back 30 years (I can select 1986):
[image]